# Show touch points in gemymotion emulator for purposes of recording

Tags: genymotion

Is it possible to configure a genymotion emulator to show touch points for the purposes of recording interactions for a tutorial, for example.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70785475/show-touch-point-using-android-jetpack-compose) for the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle showing touch points (or "taps") through the advanced developper tools widget : https://docs.genymotion.com/desktop/04_Emulating_sensors_and_features/#advanced-developer-tools